# Which of the import functions is the fastest?

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, importrange

Which of importhtml,range... can load the data fastest?

Im working on sheet where I want maybe 50 imports to be updated every 5 minutes and I want it to load the slowest time possible.

I wanna import entire pages, max size of page is A1:BZ500 but average are A1:Z150.

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: I dont know how to test it properly